# Visual C# Programmatically Scroll Web Browser that has a PDF loaded into it

Tags: c#, forms, scroll, webbrowser-control

I know there are tons of similar topics to this question, but none have the answer I am looking for.

Basically what I have is a windows form, and on this form is a webbrowser control.

What I am trying to do is use the arrow keys to allow for scrolling of the web browser.

Now when it comes to HTML pages, everything works fine.

I do the normal Document.body.scrollTop to scroll the page.

Everything works great here.

The issue is when a PDF is loaded in the browser, The document is null, and I cannot scroll.

I have tried everything I could think of,  and I have checked when a document is completed loaded if the sender object has the document filled in, for which it does not.

This kinda makes sense because I am going to assume that Document is for HTML to begin with.

Now my issue is, what do I use to make the browser scroll.  I seem to have no viable access point to the window to change its scroll position.